# Who the heck is Abd al-Hazir?

Tags: diablo-iii

As my hamfisted barbarian (who is in fact, a warrior and a gentleman) bashes his way around Diablo 3, I frequently find the writings of the Abd al-Hazir gentleman. He seems to know a lot about monsters. Who is he, and what is his story?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## He is awesome

> Abd al-Hazir is a lore enthusiast and adventurer, scribing about a lot
> of his experiences in the world of Sanctuary. He is used as a tool for
> Blizzard to describe Diablo lore on the official Diablo III webpage.

[Source](http://www.diablowiki.net/Abd_al-Hazir)

> The Writings of Abd al-Hazir are well known in the civilised parts of
> Sanctuary. They seem to both be named works as well as a collection of
> entries, such as a diary.

[Source](http://www.diablowiki.net/Writings_of_Abd_al-Hazir)

> Abd al-Hazir is a renowned gentleman, historian, and scholar. He has
> recently taken up the unprecedented task of investigating,
> researching, and compiling information about the unique locales and
> denizens of our world. All the character classes, monsters and
> locations are introduced in the official site as parts of his journal.

.

> Abd al-Hazir's writings are composed of 42 entries, each one detailing
> a monster, a location or a class. One description for his writings is:
> These pages host a collection of writings about this world known as
> Sanctuary; they are intended for readers who, like the author, are
> steeped in the arcane traditions. They paint a vivid picture of some
> of the foulest, most accursed places and creatures you may encounter
> on your travels. May the knowledge contained within guide you through
> the darkness that lies ahead...

[Source](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Abd_al-Hazir)

> **Quill Fiend**
>
> *Dear Reader,*
>
> I am Abd al-Hazir, adventurer, scholar, and researcher. I share my
> knowledge of this incredible world and its creatures through my
> insightful missives, often at grave risk to myself. Why, I was
> recently in Khanduras, where my tents were ransacked by vicious quill
> fiends! **I was able to beat them off with a shoe**, but a less bold man
> would've been fared for worse.
>
> **Abd al-Hazir**

[Source](http://www.gameshampoo.com/magazine/articles/123/diablo-3-lore---wretched-mother-quill-fiend-risen-dead.html)

Comment: Ha! A Blizard!!